# Sound issues on Blackberry 8330

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mp3, mmapi, cdma

It appears that on CDMA Blackberry 8330, almost every mp3 file I'm trying to play using J2ME, gets cut-of a few seconds before it's actual end. Does anybody has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not help, but most CDMA networks use Qcelp format and QCP files. For example all the sprint handsets I have worked on use support QCP best. So you can try this format and see if it works.